# Manipulating images with .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.drawing

I have updated my project from .NET 4.5 to .NET Core (with ASP.NET Core). I had some very simple code in my previous version that used the bitmap object from `System.Drawing` to resize an image.

As I understand `System.Drawing` cannot be used in .NET Core because it is not cross platform, but what can be used instead?

I have googled this and cannot find anything.  The only thing I can find is [this](https://github.com/imazen/Graphics-vNext) post, which has no code on it what so ever.

Comment: Found [this](http://imageresizing.net/) on the github you linked. Helpful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize images with MVC 6 on Ubuntu running ASP.NET 5 on Mono](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643720/resize-images-with-mvc-6-on-ubuntu-running-asp-net-5-on-mono)

Comment: To my understanding the .NET (Core) team is still discussing this with the Xamarin team. Xamarin built a library called SkiaSharp which is a wrapper for the cross-platform Skia library which again is the graphic library of Google Chrome. It runs under Android, iOS, Linux, Windows, etc. which would make it a perfect match for .NET Core. But as of today, they have not finished it for .NET Core (https://blog.xamarin.com/cross-platform-2d-graphics-with-skiasharp/). My bets go, that this library will be the future story for .NET Core and drawing.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Add more facts to assist @Thomas [SkiaSharp can be dated back to 2012 as part of XobotOS](http://corefx.strikingly.com/). Xamarin made it available recently, so it can be used individually, or used as the basis for future 2D rendering framework (such as System.Drawing on SkiaSharp instead of GDI+/libgdiplus). .NET Core support is tracked in https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/20

Comment: I'd be interested in advanced image manipulation like erode / dilate for core

Comment: Updated link on this topic posted January 19, 2017 by Bertrand Le Roy

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/

Comment: Have you checked out [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp) ? Awesome library that I'm using in my project now.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this? We mainly need it to convert between file formats and to get the image size and DPI.

Comment: I don't know about earlier versions of core but .NET 5 has System.Drawing integrated, it would appear. I was able to manipulate images from aspnetcore project.

Answer (score 48):

Disclaimer: This is my software.

I'm working on a cross-platform 2D Graphics library that runs on .NET Core It's currently alpha but already supports a comprehensive feature set.

https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp

Example usage.

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("foo.jpg"))
using (FileStream output = File.OpenWrite("bar.jpg"))
{
    Image image = new Image(stream);
    image.Resize(image.Width / 2, image.Height / 2)
         .Greyscale()
         .Save(output);
}
```

Comment: So what about drawing on a specific OS canvas? has anyone abstracted that away from the OS?

Comment: TK has a .Net Core library for graphics. I expect a UI lib eventually but it might wrap TK.

Comment: @IAbstract  TK, you got a link to share?

Comment: Just perfect. Zero dependencies and full range of formats. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that ImageSharp changed their license and is PAID if your company makes more than 1M/year

Comment: How is that relevant to the question?

Comment: @JamesSouth this is not relevant to the question, but this is relevant to the answer. It was posted in 2016 linking to an Apache-licensed library. Then the license has changed, but developers rarely pay attention when updating `nugets`. These things come up during legal audits later and can be very painful.

Comment: Except that it's not. The question does not specify that OSI licenses are required and the answer does not specify that the library has an OSI license. This is a forum for technical QA and licensing discussions are explicitly off topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=Legal%20questions%2C%20including%20questions%20about%20copyright%20or%20licensing%2C%20are%20off%2Dtopic%20for%20Stack%20Overflow.%20Open%20Source%20Stack%20Exchange%20or%20Law%20Stack%20Exchange%20may%20be%20suitable%20alternatives..

Answer (score 40):

You can use now official (from Microsoft) [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) NuGet package.

---

Note that's it's Windows-only starting from .NET 6 (it used to be cross-platform for .NET Core and .NET 5). It will still work in .NET 6 with special switch on other platforms.

From [Microsoft docs recommended action:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action)

To use these APIs for cross-platform apps, migrate to one of the following libraries:

- [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp)
- [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp)
- [Microsoft.Maui.Graphics](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics)

Alternatively, you can enable support for non-Windows platforms in .NET 6 by setting the `System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport` [runtime configuration switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/) to `true` in the `runtimeconfig.json` file:

```json
{
   "configProperties": {
      "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
   }
}
```

This configuration switch was added to give cross-platform apps that depend heavily on this package time to migrate to more modern libraries. However, non-Windows bugs will not be fixed. In addition, this switch has been removed in .NET 7.

Comment: @DougS No, it's cross platform. See discussion here https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20325

Comment: @DougS Yeah, I agree that headline is confusing.

Comment: See Scott Hanselman's blogg on how to use System.Drawing.Common: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoYouUseSystemDrawingInNETCore.aspx

Comment: This is bad solution due to dependencies and huge size. See @James South answer

Comment: @AlekDepler At the moment of writing answer (in 2018) library in James South answer was really buggy. I tested it and many alternatives back then. Probably it's not the best but at least I can recommend System.Drawing.Common library for enterprise solutions. It provides consistent and reliable results.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov

System.Drawing.Common is unsupported on non Windows platforms as of .NET 6 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=net-6.0#remarks

Comment: @JamesSouth I added information about .NET 6 non-Windows platforms in .NET 6. I'm grateful for your update, we didn't manage to migrate to .NET 6 so I didn't know about this.

Answer (score 16):

I've found an implementation of System.Drawing for .NET Core based on Mono's sources being maintained at:

- https://github.com/CoreCompat/CoreCompat

The NuGet package is at:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.System.Drawing

Which you can reference it in your .NET Core App's `project.json` with:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "CoreCompat.System.Drawing": "1.0.0-beta006",
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: This is prerelease software, so make sure you have the "show prerelease" box ticked.

Comment: This package has been marked deprecated and has not received any updates since June 27, 2016.

Answer (score -3):

[Aspose.Drawing](https://products.aspose.com/drawing/net) can manipulate images using API compatible with System.Drawing, fully managed and cross-platform with .NET Core 2.0+ support. (I'm one of the developers.)