# Is .NET Core stable to start a real product?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a big website that developed with MVC5 and I wanted to convert it to .Net core.

Everything works great but when I wanted to add my references to .Net core edition of my project I saw that .net core just accepts References of .net core type or some references that can be install from nuget.

I decided to convert my DLL References to .Net core dll types and because of this create a new .Net core class library but when i click to add some references to this class library like Syste.Drawing , I saw there is nothings on references list.

After some searching on google I founded some posts like

[Server-side graphics in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284346/server-side-graphics-in-asp-net-core)

[Manipulating images with .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344200/manipulating-images-with-net-core)
....

After encountering with this problem I was thinking may be it's possible I encounter with a problem like this who I can not handle it in .Net core and I should stand by until Microsoft releases a more complete edition of .net core.

Now the question is that is .net core stable to start a real project/product or
not?

Comment: My personal opinion: I did a small project ([this one](https://tm.uwe.co/)) with a beta release approx. 1 year ago. Until now I had zero outages or errors. So in my opinion, the whole thing _is_ production ready.

Comment: very funny 3 votes to close this question, it seems stackoverflow works with Microsoft and does not like some questions like this :)

Comment: Not every opinion that differs from your own opinion is necessarily a conspiracy.

Comment: This question should NOT be closed due to "Opinion-based"

Comment: Thanks David Tansey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As always the decision depends on what do you want to achieve.

ASP.NET Core is a brand new web framework with cross plattform and performance in mind. In these days "real projects" are developed based on the version 1.0. The code for 1.0 is released and supported by Microsoft - so this is production ready. The tooling itsself is in preview (Visual Studio integration).

If cross plattform is not a major requirement for you right now, then you can choose Windows as plattform for your application and you can access the whole .NET Framework including the many, many libraries of the .net world. Later on you can swap to .NET Core libraries by the time more and more libraries will support .net Core.

As it is a version 1.0 there are typical pitfalls compared to a long lived web framework like ASP.NET. Documentation is in progress or features that you might miss these days (like SignalR) can be a major no go for you.

So you have to investigate to gain the information specific to your requirements. ASP.NET Core is production ready starting point especially if you plan a new product from scratch.