# Generate EAN Barcode Using ZXing.Net and get a base64 string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, barcode, zxing

I would like to generate EAN 13 Barcode using ZXing.NET in ASP.NET and convert it to the base64 string.

I have a problem how to convert BarcodeWriterPixelData which I'm getting from:

```
BarcodeWriterPixelData writer = new BarcodeWriterPixelData()
{
   Format = BarcodeFormat.EAN_13
};
var pixelData = writer.Write(barcodeModel.BarcodeNumber);
```

I was trying by using ImageSharp

```
var base64String = string.Empty;
using (Image<Rgba32> image = Image.Load<Rgba32>(pixelData.Pixels))
{
    base64String = image.ToBase64String();
}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to do this. Add reference to `CoreCompat.System.Drawing` nuget package (it's in beta) and then use this code:

```
BarcodeWriterPixelData writer = new BarcodeWriterPixelData()
{
    Format = BarcodeFormat.EAN_13
};
var pixelData = writer.Write(barcodeModel.BarcodeNumber);

using (var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
{
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        try
        {
             // we assume that the row stride of the bitmap is aligned to 4 byte multiplied by the width of the image   
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelData.Pixels, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, pixelData.Pixels.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        }

        // PNG or JPEG or whatever you want
        bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        var base64str = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

As far as I know `ImageSharp` is not released yet. I recommended CoreCompact based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39628471/1093508).

Comment: I'm getting an error Non-invocable member 'Rectangle' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow deleted the "new" part. Edited, try now.

Comment: It works, but now I have another error on the first using statement: The type initializer for 'System.Drawing.GDIPlus' threw an exception. The whole an erro message: Message = "Unable to load DLL 'gdiplus': The specified module could not be found.\n (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

Comment: What kind of exception? I tested it on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017, .NET Core 1.1. You?

Comment: The same, but I run the app with Docker. maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Did you include all the dll-s in the container? CoreCompat.System.Drawing.dll, System.Drawing.Primitives.dll etc..? Try to do "publish" and see the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144341/discussion-between-cieja-and-david-molnar).

Comment: Oh my god dude, you are the realest MVP, you are the 5/17/2017 savior!

Answer (score 4):

You can use ImageSharp to load up the raw pixel data (assuming `pixelData.Pixels` is a byte[] containing raw rgba32 formatted pixel data). Instead of using `Image.Load<Rgba32>(data, width, height)` you should be using `Image.LoadPixelData<Rgba32>(data)`

So you final loading code would be:

```
var base64String = string.Empty;
using (Image<Rgba32> image = Image.LoadPixelData<Rgba32>(pixelData.Pixels, width, height))
{
    base64String = image.ToBase64String(ImageFormats.Png);
}
```

Basically the `Image.Load<Rgba32>(data)` api is for loading up encoded data i.e. png, jpg etc formatted data. Where as the `Image.LoadPixelData<Rgba32>(data)` api is for loading up raw pixel data into the image object for later processing/saving.